# Cloudwatch Events Reliability

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I read one of the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/automating-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-events.html) on AWS cloudwatch events and it states that

***"Note that you cannot write a program that depends on the order or existence of notification events, as they might be out of sequence or missing. Events are emitted on a best effort basis."***

Is it true for AWS cloudwatch events in general i.e. it is a best effort service and not a guaranteed one for all services on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of the AWS service. Unfortunately for "best effort" events you should consider writing custom reliability layer on the top of these events. You can find the list of services and reliability levels here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html